# How does 2D this area of integration change under this transformation?

Tags: integration

Consider the double integral (for some arbitrary function $f$)
$$
I := \int_0^{1} dx \int_{x+2}^5 dy \ f(x,y)
$$
Suppose I change variables to $(x,y) \to (u,v)$ where
$$
u = x
$$
and
$$
v = y - (x + 2)
$$
The Jacobian matrix then appears to be $J = \left[ \begin{smallmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 1 & - 1 \end{smallmatrix} \right]$, which means $|\det(J)| = 1$. Does this mean that my integral gets transformed to
$$
I = \int_0^{1} du \int_{0}^{3 - u} dv \ f(u,v + x + 2) \ ?
$$
I cannot figure out if the integration region changes for the $u$-integral?

EDIT: Fixed a typo in the integrand of the last equation.

Comment: $y = u+v+2$ in this trasformation.  The transformation is a shear.  That means that the unit square would transform into a parallogram of equal area.

Comment: The integration region for the $u$-integral does not change because $u=x$ . Make $f$ independent of $y$ and the integral will become $\int_0^1 f(x)(5-x-2)\,dx = \int_0^1 f(u)(3-u)\,du$.